# Making a cell in column B display the largest value in column A

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

I have 2 columns, H&I with numbers. The values in H correspond to different ID numbers, and I has measurements.

I am trying to figure out a formula that would post in cell K3 the highest value in column I. I also want cell L3 to say the corresponding value in column H (relative to the new highest value/new value of cell K3).

I tried to figure out an if statement that works, but I couldn't get it just right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for an `IF`, you can use an `INDEX/MATCH`:

```
=INDEX(H:H,MATCH(MAX(I:I),I:I,0))
```

`MAX(I:I)` will get the maximum value in column `I`

`MATCH` will get the row it is in

`INDEX` will then return the content of the corresponding cell in column `H`

To have both the ID and the max value, use:

```
=INDEX(H:H,MATCH(MAX(I:I),I:I,0)) & " " & MAX(I:I)
```